# Green button fill screen (as opposed to fullscreen) and coloured folders like 10.8 in El Capitan

Tags: finder, macos

In El Capitan is it possible to have coloured files in finder like 10.8 and be able to click the green button on a window to get it to fit to screen (rather than fullscreen) like you could in 10.9 ?

Answer (score 1):

1. No
2. Yes. Press the option key when pressing the green button.